# SSIS Loading Just The Date From Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, ssis, conditional-statements

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets, but only the first sheet has the date listed on it.  What I was trying to do was read the excel file, put it into a variable to be able to be used later on in a data flow task.

Normally it would be your run of the mill read and write data flow task, but since this information lies in the first page of the excel sheet with just mostly information about the report, it makes reading the information a bit more difficult.

Here's what the sheet looks like, and the only information that I was wanting from this whole sheet was on the **Data Period** line more specifically, `Dec 2016`

[image]

Any direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What you show is just text, not a date. Parts of that text field may or may not contain dates. You'd have to *parse* each value to extract whatever looks like a date

Comment: As this is tagged excel, ill provide an excel solution. In B6 add: `=Right(Trim(A6),8)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, essentially I'd pass the string into a variable and in my derived column I'd cast it using (DT_STR,10,1252)year + "-" + (DT_STR,10,1252)month+ "-31" or something like that.  It's just extracting the strings is what I'm having trouble doing.

Comment: @Luuklag you can't evaluea an Excel formula in an SSIS package

Comment: @JLone you can use a a query to load specific fields, eg `SELECT * from [Sheet1$A6:A6]` but you *still* have to process that text. If you are absolutely certain that the string would end with `MMM YYYY` you could just return the last 8 characters, either through SQL or an SSIS derived column formula. You don't need to convert the string to YYYY-MM-DD, OLEDB can parse `MMM YYYY` to a date as long as the column's locale is set to an English locale

Comment: Unclear.   What are your desired results?

Comment: @TabAlleman it's quite clear. The OP wants to extract the date from a field that contains a lot of text, not just the date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if that's true, then why is an SSIS package even needed?   If the end result is only to extract a date, a console program could do it better.  When I ask for a "desired result", I am referring to final outcome.  If you only want to get ONE DATE from the entire spreadsheet, SSIS is a terrible tool.

Comment: @TabAlleman why is any console application needed? Because it does a lot more than a single statement. The OP already explained that the value is needed in subsequent **dataflow** steps. It may be used to enumerate files based on a string pattern. It may be used as a default value for a field. It doesn't really matter

Comment: It does matter is the reason I'm asking.  The question states, "read the excel file, put it into a variable to be able to be used later on in a data flow task."  In clear English, with nothing assumed, this means OP wants to put the entire Excel file into a variable to be used in a data flow task.  The final goal of this dataflow task matters very much in advising the OP.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, then as this is not an excel problem the excel tag is obsolete and should be removed.

Comment: @Luuklag this is very much an Excel problem, just as it is an SSIS problem. How are you going to *query* specific fields? How are you going to write the query? That's Excel. How are you going to *execute* that query? How are you going to store the result in a variable? That's SSIS

Comment: @TabAlleman What I was looking to do with the date is ultimately put it into a database under a 'Report Date' column.  Since the month or year is nowhere else in the excel file except for the first page, I have to create a single data flow task to extract just the date, put it into a variable to be able to insert it into my database as `Report Date` once I load all other necessary information from the excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel sheets can be queried like tables. You can use an `Execute SQL Task` to read a range of cells iterate over the results, or you can read a single cell as if it were a range and store its value in a variable.

The process is described in [Read Excel Value in SSIS](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/11/ssis-read-excel-cell-value-in-ssis.html) and contains quite a few gotchas :

1. Add an Excel conneciton manager that points to your Excel file
2. Set its result type to `Single Row`.
3. Set the query to `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A6:A6]`. That's the first gotcha.  You can't specify column names. In a dataflow query you can write `SELECT RIGHT(F1,8) FROM
   [Sheet1$A6:A6]` to extract only the date part. This doesn't work in
   the `Execute SQL Task`.
4. In the `Result Set` section, map the `0` result set to a new string variable, eg `PeriodCell`. The name has to be 0. That's the second gotcha
5. You can create another variable based on an expression that returns only the 8 rightmost characters of `PeriodCell`, eg `RIGHT( @[User::PeriodCell],8)`

You can parse the string directly into a date if your system uses an English locale. In this case, you could create a DateTime variable with an expression `(DT_DATE)RIGHT( @[User::PeriodCell],8)`. For example, `(DT_DATE)"Dec 2016"` returns `1/1/2016`

Unfortunately, this won't work if your locale is *not* English, even if you change the package's Locale property.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably what I was missing, I tried `Select * FROM [Sheet$A6]` but it kept giving me errors.  I just settled for `A1:A6 WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL` which gave me two lines, ran it through a conditional split then a derived column to give me the **Data Period** line. All that was left was to parse through it and extract the necessary month and year.  I'll try yours to see if it's less convoluted than  mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have load the content of the cells of the "Data Period" column into a SQL table with SSIS, you can easilty convert them from excel date format to SQL date format usign one of the following:

**Date and time**

```
select dateadd(second, (@time_xls - ROUND(@time_xls,0))*86400, dateadd(d, ROUND(@time_xls,0),'1899-12-30'))
```

*For example the value 42853.4673611111 is converted into "2017-04-28 11:13:00.000"*

**Only date**

```
select dateadd(d,@time_xls,'1899-12-30')
```

*For example the value 36464 is converted into "1999-10-31 00:00:00.000".*

Comment: That's *not* what the OP asks. The string contains a lot more than just the date. Besides, `select cast('Dec 2016' as date)` will work just fine with the correct locale. The locale can be specified explicitly in the `PARSE` command, eg `select PARSE('Dec 2016' as date USING 'en-US')`

Comment: Besides, SSIS itself can parse the string if the column's type and locale are set appropriately. The hard part is extracting the date from the descriptive cell